# Combining report and apa6 class for a dissertation

Tags: report, thesis, apa6

I am a complete newcomer to LaTeX. Here is what I am attempting to do - combine a thesis template (made with the `report` class) with a template based on the `apa6` class. In other words, I need the following front matter from the thesis template (title page, abstract, dedication, acknowledgements, table of contents [including roman page numbering beginning on page iii]) and the following items from the `apa6` class template (APA style headings, reference styles, running heads, etc. (with arabic numbering beginning with the first page of chapter 1) for everything else.

The thesis code is located [here](http://etd.vt.edu/howto/tutorials/latex/etd.txt).
The `apa6` template is found in the `apa6` documentation, in particular the `shortsample.tex` file that comes with `apa6.cls`.

Any pointers here? What I should try? Where I should look next?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach:

1. download the apa6e.dtx class.
2. Change line 240 to pass the option to `report` rather than `article`

   ```
     \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}%
   ```
3. Change line 243 to load `report`

   ```
     \LoadClass[12pt]{report}
   ```

Generate the class by latexing the changed file and the `.ins` file.

The above will change the class to load the `report` rather than the `article` base class. 
In your document add the `thesis` items you want to retain in the preamble, such as the changes in geometry, load specific packages etc.

If you feel adventurous, you change the name of the class (you need to do it as per the Licence) and incorporate your own changes. Not too difficult to do, but requires a little bit of reading. Read the `clsguide` for help.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I made the changes you indicated though I couldn't figure out what to do about the .ins file. Unfortunately, being a complete newbie, I don't know what to do next. I realize there is a multitude of info online, but I'm not even sure of what I should be searching for. What resources should I be accessing to learn how to add the preamble elements I want?

Comment: @william Save everything in the directory you are going to work. pdflatex both files (.dtx and .ins) and you will have the class file generated (check for .cls incorporating your changes). The new class will be based on report. If you are not in a hurry, I can post more instructions tomorrow sometime.

Comment: More instructions would be great. Thank you.

Comment: I think I've figured out a way around this by simply adding preamble material and changing the pagestyle, page numbering by using setcounter, etc. Thank you for the help though.